# an identity regarding the chain rule for weak derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The following is from a [note](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pdes.html) in PDE:
[image]
[image]

The identity seems from the chain rule. There is no proof in the note for this statement. Would anybody explain why there is a "${}\circ\phi$" part in the identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u=v \circ \phi$, so the derivative of $v$ needs to be evaluated at $\phi(x)$ not at $x$. Cf. the one variable chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x))=g'(x) f'(g(x))$.